# Possible causes for connection interrupted, LAMP stack

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cakephp

MySQL 5.1.73
Apache/2.2.15 
PHP 5.6.13
CentOS release 6.5 
Cakephp 3.1

After about 4 minutes (3 min, 57 seconds) the import process I'm running stops.  There are no errors or warnings in any log that I can find.  The import process consists of a lot of SQL calls and data processing, nothing too crazy, but it can take about 10 minutes to get through 5500 records if it's doing a full compare for updates.

Firefox: Secure Connection Failed - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
Chrome: ERR_NO RESPONSE

1. The php set time limit is set to 900, which is working.  I can set it to 5 seconds and get an error.  The limit is not being reached.
2. I can sleep another controller for 10 minutes, and this error does not happen, indicating that something in the actual program is causing it to fail, and not the hosting service killing the request because it's taking too long (read about VPS doing this to prevent spam).
3. The php errors are turned all the way up in the php.ini, and just to be sure, in the controller itself.
4. The import process completes if I reduce the size of the file being imported.  If it's just long enough, it will complete AND show the browser message.  This indicates to me it's not failing at the same point of execution each time.
5. I have deleted all the cache and restarted the server.
6. I do not see any output in the apache logs other then that the request was made.
7. I do not see any errors in the mysql log, however, I don't know if it's because its not turned on.
8. The exact same code works on my local host without any issue.  It's not a perfect match to the server, but it's close.  Ubuntu Desktop vs Centos, php 5.5 vs php 5.6
9. I have kept an eye on the memory usage and don't see any issues there.

At this point I'm looking for any good suggestions on what else to look at or insights into what could be causing the failure.  There are a lot of possible places to look, and without an error, it's really difficult to narrow down where the issue might be.  Thanks in advance for any advice!

**UPDATE**

After taking a closer look at the memory usage during the request, I noticed it was getting much higher than it ideally should.

The httpd (apache) process gets killed and a new thread spawned.  Once the new thread runs out of memory, the error shows up on the screen.  When I had looked at it previous, it was only at 30%, probably because it had just killed the old process.  Watching it the whole way through, I saw it get as high as 80%, which with the other processes was enough to get have it run out of memory, and a killed process can't log anything, hence the no errors or warnings.  It is interesting to me that the process just starts right back up.

I found a command to show which processes had been killed due to memory which proved very useful:

dmesg | egrep -i 'killed process'

Comment: So, the server does not crash? Is it immediately accessible after the crash?

Comment: you said "The exact same code works on my local host without any issue." Are you on a shared host? Are you sure that the 900 sec max execution time is working in this server? Can you verify if there are timeouts implemented on apache?

Comment: The server is immediately accessible after the crash.  However, when I try to access a different page from a different tab, it waits until the initial import request finishes before responding.  I assume this is because it's the same session making the request.

Comment: This is not a shared host, it is private and only has one application on it.  My test to make sure the timeout was working was by setting it to under the 4 minute mark and seeing the php error.  There are timeout in the apache config, but all of them are well below 4 minutes.

Comment: point 4: "If it's just long enough..." exactly how much long? Maybe your problem is related to the size of the file, or to some counter you use to scan the file itself...

Comment: The file size does not seem to be related.  If I delete the data in the table I'm importing to and all it has to do is inserts, the time it takes is less (because there's no lookups for existing records) and it imports around the 4 minute mark.  The process is marked as complete but I still connection fail.  This indicates to me it's not the size of the file, but the duration of the processing.

Comment: Turns out it was a memory issue (see update in main post).  I may end up going to smaller batches just to reduce the chance of this happening as record sets grow over time.  Ideally though I would want to get away from the Cakephp ORM which is useful for rapid development, but wildly inefficient unless closely managed.

Answer (score 0):

I did have similar problems with debugkit.
I had bug in my code during memory peak and the context was written to html in the error "log".